# How to setup wxWidgets for hello world project with Code::Blocks?

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets, setup-project

I would like to use wxWidgets 3.0.2 library in my project. However I am unable to run even the `hello world` program. I have downloaded the headers and the appropriate binaries (TDM GCC x64 4.8.1). I've extracted them without any changes. So there are include and libs folders present in my wxWidgets folder. I am using TDM-GCC 5.1 which is setup properly. 
When I create a simple console application and only include the main file

```
#include "C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\wx.h"
```

I get an error

```
C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\wx.h|14|fatal error: wx/defs.h: No such file or directory|
```

Which is quite reasonable, as `defs.h` is in the same folder as `wx.h` and there is no wx folder inside. Do I need to rearrange the file structure? 
Is the compiler problem here (5.1 used instead of 4.8.1)? 
For three days I am running trough different tutorials, and all the time I get this or similar errors. How to set it up properly?

The whole code is just:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "C:\wxWidgets\include\wx\wx.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never include wxWidgets (or any other library) header files using full paths. Instead you should have just

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
```

in your code and set up your compiler headers search path to include `c:\wxWidgets\include` directory. Notice that you will also need to add `c:\wxWidgets\lib\gcc481_lib\mswu` or similar to the includes path, depending on the exactl configuration you're using (e.g. it could be `gcc481_dll` if you're using the DLL build).